# Ajax call not working after page reload.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have my home page in php with checkboxes by the names of brand and store list.and in the end one submit button which is given below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_check_value() {
        var c_value = [];

        $('input[name="brand"]:checked').each(function () {
            c_value.push(this.value);
        });
        return c_value.join(',');

    }
    function get_store_value(){
    var d_value=[];
        $('input[name="store"]:checked').each(function () {
            d_value.push(this.value);
        });
        return d_value.join(',');
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function (e)
   {e.preventDefault();
    alert("hi");
        //var os = $('#originState').val();
       //var c = $('#commodity').val();
        //var ds = $('#destState').val();
        var ser = get_check_value();
        var store=get_store_value();
        //var queryString = "os=" + os;
        var data = "?ser=" + ser;
        var queryString = "&ser=" + ser;
        alert(ser);
       $.ajax({
       //alert("ajax");
        type: "POST",
        url: "sortingajax.php",
        data: {ser:ser,store:store},
        dataType :  'html',
        success: function (b) {
           // alert(a+' ok. '+b)
            $('#results').html(b);
            console.log(b);
        }
    });

  });
 });

</script>


brand
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Sunbaby" />Sunbaby
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Advance Baby" />Advance Baby
    <br/>
    store
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="store" value="JCPenny" />JCPenny
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="store" value="Supermart" />Suoermart
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="store" value="Target" />Target
    <br/>


<button id="btnSubmit">sort</button>
<div id="results">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On click of submit,button it goes for ajax call and displays the result in results div.

```
<?php

include('connection.php');
$query=$_POST['ser'];
$query1=$_POST['store'];
echo $query;
echo $query1;

$query=explode(",",$query);
$query = array_filter($query);
$query1=explode(",",$query1);
$query1 = array_filter($query1);
$result=count($query);
$result1=count($query1);
//echo $result;
echo $result1;
$parts = array();
$limit = 10;
    $offset = 0;
if(!empty($query))
{
foreach( $query as $queryword ){
    $parts[] = '`BRAND` LIKE "%'.$queryword.'%"';

}
$brandsql='SELECT * FROM XML WHERE  ('.implode ('OR',$parts).')  order by price asc';
    $brandsql1=mysql_query($brandsql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($brandsql1);  
$countArray=array();
print($brandsql);
echo "<br />";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($brandsql1)) {
    // Append to the array


    $countArray[] = $row;



    //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
}
}
$parts1=array();
if(!empty($query1)){
foreach( $query1 as $queryword1 ){
    $parts1[] = '`STORE` LIKE "%'.$queryword1.'%"';

}
$storesql='SELECT * FROM XML WHERE  ('.implode ('OR',$parts1).') order by price desc';
    $storesql1=mysql_query($storesql);
$numrows1 = mysql_num_rows($storesql1); 
$countArray=array();
print($storesql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($storesql1)) {
    // Append to the array


    $countArray[] = $row;



    //echo $row['PID']."<BR />";
}
}
?>


<?php
foreach($countArray as $array)
{



?>

<div>
hi</div>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

But  iF I refresh my page or press F5 from keyboard,after getting content in results div,it goes back to previous content i.e.first page with checkboxes and submit button.
Please tell me where m doing wrong in the code or what do i need to include so that after ajax call if i refresh the page,content should remain same,should not go to previous content...

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` to run a refresh on the page after X seconds inside the AJAX callback, after you display content.

Comment: we can give time limit of that ajax call according to our ease.That till that time we want to be on that ajax called page.is it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `_SESSION` variable in your PHP script to store what checkboxes were selected most recently, and display results on your results div, appropriately.

Although, if a user clicks refresh he might want to reset the choices he made anyway. You could give him a warning that his changes will be lost if he refreshes.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return confirm("You have made changes to this form. Do you want to continue without saving these changes?");   
}
```